# Storybook fails to show an image that's directly imported by a React component

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, storybook

I'm using Storybook 5 with create-react-app, TypeScript and [create-react-app-preset](https://github.com/storybookjs/presets/tree/master/packages/preset-create-react-app)

I have a loader component:

```
import React from 'react'
import src '../../../assets/img/loading.gif'

const Loader = ({ width, height }) => {

    return (
        <div className="loading">
            <img
                style={{width, height}}
                src={src}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

The component works just fine inside my app, bud the image is broken in Storybook - the src doesn't get through:

[image: story]
[image]

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: i had the same error, (only on one component, super weird ) .....try this on a div.....style={{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + require('../../../assets/img/loading.gif') + ')'

Comment: from your screenshot it shows that `src` has appropriate value in `props`. Is that true ? I mean to say webpack config from storybook is able to resolve img file path?

Comment: I have same problem. Did you find solution for this?